# How to load a file into a class scope

Tags: ruby

In `InterfaceServer#initialize`, I intend to build a path to a file, and load the file into `InterfaceServer` class's scope.

This is my code:

```
class InterfaceServer
  def initialize(channel)
    @channel_path = channel + "_implementation"
  end

  require_relative @channel_path
end
```

I get this error:

```
error => `require_relative': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

Wrapping the `require_relative` statement in a method would solve the problem, but it defeats my requirement for the file to be loaded into the class's scope.

The problem is associated with scope gates, but I can't make it work. I read that instance variables are accessible to all methods in the class. Why am I getting the error?
 Can anyone help with a solution?

Comment: _"I read that instance variables are accessible to all methods in the class so why am I getting the error?"_ – because your `require_relative` call is not inside a method.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the reply. But i really require the file to be loaded in the class as it contains modules i plan to use in the class. Can you suggest a workaround please?

Comment: That makes no sense. `require_relative` simply runs the file. Where the call to `require_relative` is, has no influence whatsoever.

Comment: What Jörg said. Also, you want to do something at class level before any instance is created, yet __requiring data from instance initializer__. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "The problem is associated with scope gates" - scope gates have __nothing__ to do with this. But yes, it's a matter of scope, class vs instance.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ohh I see ... I thought It loads the script into the file. I'm really sorry for my ignorance. But with what i plan to do is there a workaround that i can use? I need a mechanism to add the script in the file to the class because it holds some extensions to the class.

Comment: Well, if the script file holds extensions to the class, then running it will add those extensions to the class.

Comment: @W.J.A from the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require): _"Any constants or globals within the loaded source file will be available in the calling program’s global namespace."_ Once the file is loaded, you can add it (i.e. its modules) to your class via `include` and `extend`.

Answer (score 3):

Instance variables belong to objects ("instances"), that's why they are *called* instance variables. You have two completely different objects here: `InterfaceServer` and an instance of `InterfaceServer`. They are different objects (after all, they don't even the same class! `InterfaceServer` has class `Class`, the instance of `InterfaceServer` has class `InterfaceServer`), so they have different instance variables as well.

> My code requires a file to be loaded into the `InterfaceServer` class's scope.
>   […]
>   Wrapping the `require_relative` statement in a method would solve the problem, but it defeats my requirement for the file to be loaded into the class's scope.

`require_relative` simply runs the file. It has nothing to do with scopes. Where the call to `require_relative` is located is irrelevant.

(Oh, and also: `require_relative` is not a statement, it is an expression. In fact, there are no statements in Ruby, everything is an expression.)

> The problem is associated with scope gates

Nope, it isn't.

> I read that instance variables are accessible to all methods in the class.

Instance variables belong to instances. They have nothing to do with methods.

> Why am I getting the error?

The instance variable `@channel_path` of `InterfaceServer` has nothing to do with the instance variable `@channel_path` of the *instance of* `InterfaceServer`. Since you never assigned to the instance variable `@channel_path` of `InterfaceServer`, it doesn't exist, and non-existing instance variables evaluate to `nil`, ergo you are calling `require_relative` with `nil` as an argument.

> Can anyone help with a solution?

Not really, since you haven't stated the problem. What you are doing is a) impossible (there are multiple instances of the class, so which instance's `@channel_path` should be used?) and b) non-sensical (there is no such thing as "`require`ing a file into a class's scope).

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Jorg

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. I've found a solution to what I was trying to do. Apparently, what i was trying to implement can be done using the decorator design pattern. I got some code and more explanation from the book Design Patterns In Ruby by Russ Olsen. Thanks for helping out! I really appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

`require_relative @channel_path` is called when Ruby loads the `InterfaceServer` class, but `@channel_path` is only defined later when the class is instantiated.

If you want to define which modules to load into the class at runtime, you could put the methods you want to include from the '_implementation' files in different modules, and `include` each module in the class.

```
class InterfaceServer; end

channels.each do |channel|
  InterfaceServer.include Object.const_get(channel.capitalize)
end
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that `Class.new` thing in the initializer? It won't work as you think it would

Comment: It defines a new anonymous class, which you can assign to a constant (like `A = Class.new`) or inherit from (`a = Class.new; class A < a; end`.

Comment: But you don't assign it. And return value of initializer is ignored.

Comment: Thanks a mil @steenuil 
You've been most helpful. It's the latter that I want to do!
I'm really grateful!

Comment: You need a very very very good reason to play with overriding `.new`. And here you don't do it correctly.

Comment: @steenuil: yes, it does. Also its very purpose is to create classes. Suppose, you wanted to do the same thing here (which you don't, as confirmed by OP). Judging from class name, `InterfaceServer.new` creates servers, not server classes. That's the violation of contract/principle-of-least-surprise. But you can have `InterfaceServerFactory.create` (or something) for your class creation needs. So, if you remove the first part of your answer, which is a total shot-in-the-dark (and doesn't work anyway, see Jörg's answer), I'll retract my downvote.

Comment: Point taken. I removed the first part.

Comment: @steenuil: JFYI, if you want someone to see your comment, you `@mention` them. Otherwise, they may never come back to the post.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've found a solution to what I was trying to do. Apparently, what i was trying to implement can be done using the decorator design pattern. I got some code and more explanation from the book Design Patterns In Ruby by Russ Olsen. Thanks for helping out! I really appreciate.